# QT приложение не запускается (0xc000a200)

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Есть приложение которое собиралось и запускалось на Qt 5.12 с комплектом MSVC 17 64b. После имел неосторожность установить обновленную версию Qt. Дальше приложение по прежнему собиралось но на запуске выкидывает (0xc000a200). Сносить новую версию qt не вариант, да и все таки хочу понять в чем дело

Comment: Каталог сборки удалял?

Comment: Скорее всего несовместимость с новыми библиотеками, которые подхватываются из переменных окружения. Одни (старые, или новые) для сборки - другие для запуска (новые, или старые). Надо проверить окружение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла переустановка комплекта. Я с начало удалил старую версию QT , потом установил те комплекты которые нудны были для старых проектов и все четко заработало. Ошибка была в установке QT, мне было достаточно установить новые комплекты , а не весь QT.